# How do I pull out a total of 4 rows from all my matrix blocks?

Tags: templating

I have an entry that has a matrix field, which has a table in it; I am trying to pull out 4 rows from the latest block, but if there aren't 4 rows then I would like it to pull out the remainder from the older blocks (So I always have 4 items displayed, even if the latest matrix block only has 1 table row in it).

This is what I have so far, but this is pulling out the latest 4 rows from EACH matrix block, so if I have 2 blocks it displays 8 items.

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionName').find() %}
    {% for block in entry.matrixField %}

    {% if block.type == "blockType" %}

        {% for row in block.tableField | slice(0, 4) %} <!-- I tried .limit(4) here too -->
            {{ row.title }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want four rows from each entry. I would do it like this using `{% break %}` from the [break and continue](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mnbreakandcontinue) plugin:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionName').find() %}
  {# restart our count for the new entry #}
  {% set numberOfRows = 0 %}

  {% for block in entry.matrixField %}
    {% if block.type == "blockType" %}
      {% for row in block.tableField.limit(4) %}

        {# bail if we've done our 4 rows #}
        {% if 4 <= numberOfRows %} {% break %} {% endif %}

        {{ row.title }}
        {# done another row, count it #}
        {% set numberOfRows = numberOfRows + 1 %}

      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {# bail if we've done our 4 rows #}
    {% if 4 <= numberOfRows %} {% break %} {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, slightly less efficiently (but maybe simpler), like this without that plugin:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionName').find() %}
  {% set numberOfRows = 0 %}
  {% for block in entry.matrixField %}

    {% if block.type == "blockType" %}
      {% for row in block.tableField.limit(4) %}

        {% if numberOfRows < 4 %}
          {{ row.title }}
          {% set numberOfRows = numberOfRows + 1 %}
        {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't think you pull out the four rows from multiple matrix blocks with a single query.

Comment: Cheers Marion, that second code snippet was perfect!